# Filter entities with null parent using `Objectify` on datastore

Tags: java, objectify, datastore

In my model I have

```java
@Entity
public class Ent implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private long key;

  @Parent
  private Key<Ent> parentKey;
}
```

entity which creates a simple hierarchy (actually just 2-levels in my case). I would like to filter for just the roots of the hierarchy, which is defined by having no parent (`parentKey = null`).

I tried using `filter()` in Objectify, but got an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Parent fields cannot be filtered on. Perhaps you wish to use filterKey() or ancestor() instead?
```

Then I tried using `ancestor()`, but it seems to not support `null` values:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "pojo" is null
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.SizeLimitHandler.handle(SizeLimitHandler.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:269)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:100)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:184)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchServletRequest(RequestRunner.java:262)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchRequest(RequestRunner.java:227)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.run(RequestRunner.java:193)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:273)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "pojo" is null
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Keys.getMetadataSafe(Keys.java:70)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Keys.rawKeyOf(Keys.java:52)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Keys.anythingToRawKey(Keys.java:122)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryImpl.setAncestor(QueryImpl.java:221)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.SimpleQueryImpl.ancestor(SimpleQueryImpl.java:69)
    at
```

I suppose I should use `filterKey()`, the question is how do I create a "filtering key" that will accept any `id`, but only `null` parent...

### Edit

It's probably not possible, my data actually doesn't encode `parentKey` inside the entity's `key`, which is necessary for `@Parent` feature, removing that annotation solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to give you bad news, but I don't think you can. There's no index for "entities which don't have an ancestor". It's just not a datastore operation.

I would add an indexed field to your entities to enable the query you want. You may have to map/reduce across all of your entities, resaving them to add the field.

Comment: That's weird, I was doing this kind of query fine with `javax.jdo.PersistenceManager` just adding `parentKey = null` to the filter. I do have some indexes, not sure they are related to this particular query, but my problem is with `Objectify` not being able to express the same query.

Comment: Maybe the JDO plugin added an extra synthetic indexed field? I'm not familiar with JDO, but if you can express the query using Google's low level API, I can explain how to do it with Objectify.

Comment: Here's an idea that you might have to experiment with. It's possible that all parented keys sort either before or after all non-parented keys. So try `filterKey("<", keyOf(0)` or `filterKey(">", keyOf(Long.MAX_VALUE)`?  (where keyOf is pesudocode, construct a real key with the appropriate kind)

Comment: in fact I see I had an `appengine-generated` dir with an index spec:    `<datastore-index kind="Ent" ancestor="false" source="auto"> <property name="parentKey" direction="asc"/> <property name="numComments" direction="desc"/> <property name="modificationDate" direction="desc"/>  </datastore-index>`
So I'm wondering if there is a way to generate similar query that will hit this kind of index.

But your suggestion looks interesting, I will give it a try in a few days.

Comment: Oh, I see my error, my model never actually used the datastore's `parent` concept, it just happens to define a parent reference field, but it's not encoded inside key in any way. Sorry for the confusion, I'm porting a long forgotten project from 10 years ago. :)
Removing `@Parent` annotation solved the query issue.